# Add arrow to custom validation div

Tags: html, css

This is my code:: http://prntscr.com/8cfvmi.

I need to add such arrow to my div: http://prntscr.com/8cfwok How can I add such arrow to my div?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L5cvsm9/)

```
.user-validation-error{
display:none;
font-size:13px;
border: 1px solid red;
position:absolute; 
z-index:99;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color:#d9534f;
color:white; 
right: 65px;
top: 75px;
height: 25px;
padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 0):

The common "trick" is to use the pseudo elements `::after` and `::before` in CSS.

You can save a lot of time by using this website : http://cssarrowplease.com/